# How to Serializer IEnumerable Object in silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

ICloneable is not available in Silverlight 4(I don't know about 1/2/3 or upcoming version) . It is removed from Silverlight 4's public APIs.

I have these classes :

```
public class LayerDto 

{

public MetaItemDtoList MetaItems;

}

public class MetaItemDtoList : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection 
{ 
}
```

I want to create clone of `IEnumerable<LayerDto>`.
I am trying to do this. but not getting metaItems

```
public static IEnumerable Clone(IEnumerable<LayerDto> source)

{
        IEnumerable<LayerDto> layers;

        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(IEnumerable<LayerDto>));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, source);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            //return (IEnumerable<LayerDto>)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
            layers = (IEnumerable<LayerDto>)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
            return layers;
        }
 }
```

Comment: What is type of source object that you're passing to WriteObject?

Comment: Try out mark this property with  `[XmlArray("MetaItems", IsNullable = false)]` attribute

Comment: Hasan It is type of LayerDto.(sorry some mistake it was not copyed)

Comment: Thanks Sll for reply but It is not working.

Comment: Thanks Sll for reply but It is not working. This below code is more about LayerDto class                                              private MetaItemDtoList _metaItems = new MetaItemDtoList();                                                            public MetaItemDtoList MetaItems
        {
            get
            {
                if (_metaItems == null)
                    _metaItems = new MetaItemDtoList();
                return _metaItems;
            }
            set
            {
                _metaItems = value;
            }
        }

Comment: Hasan - see this http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/694708/serializer-ienumerable-object-in-silverlight